# xslt (1.0): Add a child node to the outermost element?

Tags: xslt, identity

Struggling to work this one out; I have a (Tomcat6 'Context.xml') default document, which is essentially this:

```
<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

And I want to add 'Resource' and 'Environmment as children of the outermost Context node; so I end up with:

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource name="abc"[...]/>
    <Environment name="xyz"[...]/>
</Context>
```

Using XSLT 1.0.

(I also would like to avoid the assumption that the node 'WatchedResource' is present in the document.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:param name="new">
  <Resource name="abc..."/>
  <Environment name="xyz..."/>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="Context">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$new"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    <Resource name="abc"/>
    <Environment name="xyz"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<Context>
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Context>
   <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
   <Resource name="abc"/>
   <Environment name="xyz"/>
</Context>
```

**Do Note**: No dependency on names of existing element names and on whether or how many children of the top element exist in the document.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ticked the other answer as 'accepted' as has the extra '$new' variable, which I liked for extra-readibility.

Comment: @monojonny, You are welcome. I intentionally didn't use a parameter, because from your question it seemed that the insertions are to be done inline.